# Configuring environmental paths in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, tesseract

My Rails app works perfectly well on my machine via localhost, but when I deployed it to Heroku I got this list of errors:

```
2012-11-11T04:59:20+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e production -p 38941`
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4/lib/ffi/inline/builders/c.rb:114:in `shared_object'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4/lib/ffi/inline/compilers/gcc.rb:29:in `compile': compile error: see logs at /tmp/.ffi-inline-18803/85aad7364f11885370e58c4391df70e29ef22bbe.log (CompilationError)
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4/lib/ffi/inline/builders.rb:87:in `instance_eval'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4/lib/ffi/inline/builders.rb:87:in `build'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4/lib/ffi/inline/inline.rb:39:in `inline'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4/lib/ffi/inline/inline.rb:54:in `singleton_inline'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c.rb:34:in `<module:C>'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c.rb:31:in `<module:Tesseract>'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/api.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4/lib/ffi/inline/builders.rb:90:in `block in build'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract-ocr.rb:35:in `<top (required)>'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+
00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `require'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `run_command'
2012-11-11T04:59:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:151:in `run!'
2012-11-11T04:59:34+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-11-11T04:59:38+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed)
```

I can't seem to make heads or tails of this, other than that Heroku may be having some issues with the [Ruby Tesseract gem](https://github.com/meh/ruby-tesseract-ocr) I'm using. Maybe a problem with a dependency?

UPDATE:

After some further searching, it turns out that [the issue is related to the Tesseract gem](https://github.com/meh/ruby-tesseract-ocr/issues/3).

According to the support ticket I need to set these paths...

```
ENV['CFLAGS'] = '-I/path/to/the/headers'
ENV['LDFLAGS'] = '-L/path/to/the/libs'
```

...but I don't know how to set them or what the paths to the headers/libs should actually be on a Rails app deployed to Heroku. Any insights?

Comment: please show your log file, to see logs, type `heroku logs` in your command line.

Comment: The code I'd pasted above is the output from `heroku logs`.

Comment: Okay, I found a closed ticket about the same issues on the Tesseract-OCR gem github: https://github.com/meh/ruby-tesseract-ocr/issues/3 Not sure how or where to set these `ENV['CFLAGS']` values in the context of Heroku, though.

Comment: nice, hope you will find the way soon :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the reply from Heroku to a ticket I raised with them regarding this:

---

Hello,

Unfortunately we don't support installing additional libraries or binaries to our stacks. The best workaround is to vendor these into your project. You'll need to use 64-bit Linux versions to make them work on Heroku; compiling statically can also help ensure that any dependencies needed are included. Similarly, for gems that depend on external libraries, we recommend compiling the gem statically and vendoring it into your project.

We realize this is not a trivial task and can be very difficult to get working, and we hope to provide an easier way to do this in the future. Unfortunately we do not have an ETA on when this improved functionality will be available.

If you do wish to try to vendor your binary, library, or gem, you can use Heroku as your build environment. One of our engineers created a build server that allows you to upload source code, run the compilation step, and then download the resulting binary. You can find this project here:
https://github.com/heroku/vulcan

Thanks,
Heroku Support

---

In other words, go and deploy someplace else.

Comment: It took Heroku 8 days to send this reply to my ticket, by the way. This is the third time I've had to wait a week or longer to get an answer to a support ticket with them.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue as well so hopefully we can help each other.

I found [a way to set config var on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). Based on meh's comment on github, looks like it needs Tesseract installation on Heroku. Perhaps you could ask Heroku where is the installed location?

I also found this [other gem](https://github.com/dannnylo/tesseract_bin) mentioned to be successful in integrating to Heroku. Unfortunately, it's still using tesseract 2.04 though.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still digging around with this, and have an open support ticket with Heroku. Word on the street, though, is that this might be a doomed endeavor--Heroku support for C libraries is not supposed to be terribly strong. I'll post any helpful updates here, though.

Comment: @Michael Did you ever manage to get tesseract running on Heroku?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Unfortunately, no--I ended up just moving everything to AWS. It was a bit of a pain, but definitely worth it in the long run.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the response. Did you happen to check out https://github.com/marcolinux/heroku-buildpack-tesseract or https://github.com/dannnylo/tesseract_bin by any chance?