# Implementing OCR for Heroku Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ocr, tesseract

I need OCR capability for a Rails app on Heroku. My efforts to get tesseract to work have not been successful. Does anyone have any suggestions? It's hard to believe that something as basic as OCR isn't supported on something as ubiquitous as Rails on Heroku.

BACKGROUND ON EFFORT TO GET TESSERACT TO WORK

- Application works fine on MacOS using tesseract binaries and tesseract-ocr gem
- Heroku doesn't have built-in tesseract support and doesn't support installing binaries (see [Configuring environmental paths in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328785/configuring-environmental-paths-in-heroku/13464637#13464637))
- Most SO questions about tesseract on Heroku don't have answers ([Using Tesseract on Heroku with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521976/using-tesseract-on-heroku-with-django), [Tesseract-OCR on Heroku with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558406/tesseract-ocr-on-heroku-with-node-js))
- Can't get [tesseract_bin](https://github.com/dannnylo/tesseract_bin) gem to load locally (haven't tried on Heroku)
- Route of using [buildpack-libraries](https://github.com/marcolinux/heroku-buildpack-libraries) seems overwhelming to me (and if that approach is viable, I don't understand why someone hasn't provided a pre-packaged solution)

SPECIFIC ERROR LOADING TESSERACT_BIN gem

```
/Users/palfvin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pathname.rb:422:in `open': No such file or directory - /Users/palfvin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@avlats/gems/tesseract_bin-1.0.2/bin (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Users/palfvin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pathname.rb:422:in `foreach'
    from /Users/palfvin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pathname.rb:422:in `children'
    from /Users/palfvin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@avlats/gems/tesseract_bin-1.0.2/lib/tesseract_bin.rb:7:in `<module:TesseractBin>'
    from /Users/palfvin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@avlats/gems/tesseract_bin-1.0.2/lib/tesseract_bin.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/palfvin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require'
    from /Users/palfvin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/palfvin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from tmp/tesseract.rb:261:in `<main>'
```

Comment: "something as basic as OCR" I think OCR is one of the most difficult tasks in the world, second possibly to speech recognition. On another note, a buildback is probably the way to go, as that's the sanctioned way to add your own binaries to what's available on the Heroku dynos.

Comment: Thanks. I of course didn't mean "basic" as "easy to implement algorithmically", but rather "something with a simple interface (image => text) that a lot of apps would want".

Comment: I supposed that! :) It was like funny to see those two words in the same sentence...

Answer (score 4):

I developed a simple server in RoR for Heroku that uses Tesseract OCR. The server receives jpg images, runs the OCR and returns the text as string. This could be a good starting point for you.

> https://github.com/fouady/RoR-Tesseract-Heroku

Also, I use a custom buildpack which I have modified for myself. You will find the details here:

> https://github.com/fouady/heroku-buildpack-tesseract

I hope this solves your problem.